# joomla article read more displays category archive

Tags: php, joomla, categories

I want to display an article and I don't want the home page modules to be displayed in the article so I have created a menu called announcements and then I have created menu item `Article=>Category` Blog. I have selected the category announcements in that. Now the category blog works fine.

The URL is *mysite.com/index,php/my-announcements*.

But when I click on read more on the article, or when I click on article name, it does not take me to that article.

The URL is *mysite.com/index.php/my-announcements/id-article-name*

But the page contents are of category only not of article.

You can check them here:
**1.** Category Blog here
**2.** Article in that Category here

Am I missing any configuration or what?

My joomla version is 3.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your article menu is being displayed in all pages of the website. Go to menu assignment in your module and select display on only home page. Your rest of the part seems to be configured correctly.If the problem still persists, comment here.